# How to create wordpress class with post meta?

Tags: posts

I am trying to make something like this.

```
<?php 
class themeSettings {

    private $key = 'themeSettings';

    public function __construct( $key ) {
        global $post;
        $post_id = $post->ID;

        $settings = get_post_meta( $post_id, $this->key, true );
    }

    public function getData(){
        print_r( $settings['post_description'] );
    }
}

$themeSettings = new themeSettings();
?>

<?php
// Print 'post_description' values
getData();
?>
```

But it doesn't work. Where i am wrong?

Comment: Use `$themeSettings->getData();` and not just `getData();`..

Comment: same error. sory.

Comment: `$settings` is local variable, exists only in constructor, it's undefined inside `getData()`.  `$settings` should be a class property, not a variable.

Comment: @nmr is correct. So you could add `private $settings;` to your `class`, then in the `__construct()` and `getData()`, use `$this->settings` instead of `$settings`.

Comment: But there is one more problem with your class - you use global `$post` variable in its constructor - but this variable may not be initialized (depending on when the constructor will be executed). Another problem is that you run `getData()` and not `$themeSettings->getData()`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this. This should work. You don't need to use construct if you call `getData`in your theme files. You key need to be static value. After that you can call it like `self::$key`

Use like this : `echo $theme->getData(get_the_ID());` inform me if code works :)

```
<?php
class themeSettings {

    private static $key= 'themeSettings'; // We Need to create a static value
    public $id; // we nedd this for postID

    public function __construct() {}

    public function getData($id){
        //$des = get_the_title($id); For Testing
        $des =  get_post_meta($id,self::$key,true);
        /** All these area and If clause for testing */
        if($des){
            //return print_r($des); For testing
            return print_r($des['post_description']);
        } else {
            return 'Yok';
        }
    }
}

$theme = new themeSettings();

/**
 * Simple usage $theme->getData(get_the_ID());
 * Dont add global WordPress values to classes.
 */
```

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to help :)